# GKE helm connect to registry

Tags: gcloud, artifactory

I want to connect to the registry with gcloud token, Unfortunately when I try the command I have no return

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy XXXX  \
  --flatten="bindings[].members" \
  --format='table(bindings.role)' \
  --filter="bindings.members:cicd@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
roles/artifactregistry.admin
roles/owner

gcloud auth activate-service-account cicd@XXX.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=key.json --project=XXXXX

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token | helm registry login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev
^C
```

Why I am not authenticate ? I have the admin role of artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried your lines and it worked. I think what you are missing was switching to the service account

```bash
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json

# now login
$ gcloud auth application-default print-access-token | helm registry login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://europe-docker.pkg.dev
```